# Dynamically change the place of a paragraph using jQuery's toggleClass()

Tags: jquery, html, css

This actually seems pretty simple and I'm kind of surprised that it doesn't work:
So, I have this copyright text(`<p>`) that sticks to the bottom of the page using the `bottom: 0` **CSS** property.

But I also have a `<div>` with `display: none` which then appears with **jQuery**'s `.slideToggle()` function and significantly increases the height of the webpage and creates a scrollbar—that wasn't needed before.

The problem is, the copyright text doesn't automatically go to the new "bottom" of the page unless I'm using **jQuery**'s `.css()` function. But `.css()` doesn't have a "toggle" option—as far as I know, at least—so I can't bring it back up when the bar disappears again.

So I tried using the `toggleClass()` function to make it work. For some reason, it doesn't to anything at all.

Here's the—simplified—code:
**HTML**:

```
<div id="fullInfo">Some Text</div>
<p class="copyright">&copy; 2015 by THE COMPANY NAME. All rights reserved.</p>
```

**CSS**:

```
div#fullInfo {
    width: 102%;
    height: 448px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 490px;
    display: none;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: -17px;
}


p.copyright {
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -7px;
    left: 40%;
}

.togged {
    bottom: -307px;
}
```

**JavaScript**/**jQuery**:

```
$("#button").click(function(){
     $("#fullInfo").slideToggle();
     $(".copyright").toggleClass("togged");
});
```

---

It worked when I added `!important` to `.togged` in **CSS** but from what I heard, it should be used very sparingly.
So is there some other way to fix this?

Comment: @billyonecan What do you mean?

Comment: p.togged is what he means. Or do an ID for it. Not sure if that'll work. Been awhile since I've dealt with css hierarchy

Comment: I... see. Dunno why or how, but that actually worked. I'd mark it if it were an answer.

Comment: `p.copyright` has a greater specificity than `.togged` does, so the `.togged` rule is overridden by the `p.copyright` rule

Comment: There's css hierarchy. Tags > Ids > Classes. I think is somewhat how they go.

Comment: there's a good article which describes specificity [here](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/)

Comment: What if you suddenly have more content than now? Or less? Then your footer position will brake. Check this out, it is a very nice implementation of a footer that behaves just as you want, and can handle any size of content. http://cbracco.me/css-sticky-footer-effect/

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try this

```
p.copyright.togged {
    bottom: -307px;
}
```

Demo here:https://jsfiddle.net/nr82mzd1/